# How to fix net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE in webView android

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

after update chrome to last version (75.0.3370.143) my app which use webView is showing error when load data.

> "Web page not available The web page at data:text/html;
>   charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8;base64, could not be loaded because:
>   net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE"

when I disable the chrome or use old version all thing will be good.

my code to load data is

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(basePath, resource, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64", null);
```

i trying to use base64

```
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(resource.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

but the error is not fixed.

i also trying to delete css and javascript which use with my resource, also the problem is still happened.

i sure the problem happened when i update chrome to last version, but can not find the reason.